# Post request on Android to .php file

Tags: java, php, json, http-post

I'm trying to make a POST request from my android app to a `.php` file but it doesn't work. It should send the `scannedData` value to my `.php` script but instead it returns `"false: 500"`.

Does anybody know why? Since they changed that you can't use `httppost` anymore most of the answers on StackOverflow are outdated.

```
public class SendRequest extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    protected void onPreExecute(){}

    protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
        try{
            //Enter script URL Here
            URL url = new URL("https://example.com/code.php");
            JSONObject postDataParams = new JSONObject();

            //int i;
            //for(i=1;i<=70;i++)

            //    String usn = Integer.toString(i);

            //Passing scanned code as parameter
            postDataParams.put("sdata",scannedData);
            Log.e("params",postDataParams.toString());
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setReadTimeout(15000 /* milliseconds */);
            conn.setConnectTimeout(15000 /* milliseconds */);
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            conn.setDoInput(true);
            conn.setDoOutput(true);

            OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
            BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
                    new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
            writer.write(getPostDataString(postDataParams));

            writer.flush();
            writer.close();
            os.close();

            int responseCode=conn.getResponseCode();

            if (responseCode == HttpsURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {

                BufferedReader in=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
                StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("");
                String line="";

                while((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line);
                    break;
                }

                in.close();
                return sb.toString();
            }
            else {
                return new String("false : "+responseCode);
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            return new String("Exception: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), result,
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
}

public String getPostDataString(JSONObject params) throws Exception {
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    boolean first = true;

    Iterator<String> itr = params.keys();

    while(itr.hasNext()){
        String key= itr.next();
        Object value = params.get(key);

        if (first)
            first = false;
        else
            result.append("&");

        result.append(URLEncoder.encode(key, "UTF-8"));
        result.append("=");
        result.append(URLEncoder.encode(value.toString(), "UTF-8"));
    }
    return result.toString();
}
```

Comment: Have you tasted in postman ?

Comment: @Dhruv no only in Android Studio but that should also work fine

Comment: Code seems fine may be something wrong with your API so kindly first check in postman.

Comment: @Dhruv maybe because I changed the sendrequest method from "GET" to "POST" could that be a problem?

Comment: Might be possible, Please confirm with your API provider.